# Encoding problems when writing to the console in node.js

Tags: node.js, encoding

I'm having problems with the encoding in node.js. I'm running it on windows and for example if I run this simple program:

```
console.log("trying áéíóú");
```

I get in the console:

> trying ?????

Is this normal? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your console is not capable of handling certain characters the way it is currently configured. Check in the settings and see if you can enable different character sets. You probably want to use Unicode.

Comment: and how I configure windows console (cmd) to do so or how can I use unicode?